# How to add action button(custom VF) to salesforce1(mobile) only on Custom Page Layout

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have VF page want to create action and add them to only salesforce1(mobile) not salesforce classic

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at the following section of the Apex Docs: [DescribeQuickActionResult Properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_quickaction_describequickactionresult.htm%23apex_QuickAction_DescribeQuickActionResult_properties), particularly `showquickactionlcheader` and `showquickactionvfheader`. Setting the 1st one to 'true' will cause it to be visible on a lightning or SF1 Mobile page. Setting the 2nd one to 'false' will prevent the action from being displayed on the page when in Classic View.